vite generates duplicated styles and scripts links in laravel
I used Vite in a laravel Blade template like this:
@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])

But when I open the page source in the Browser I see this :
<link rel="preload" as="style" href="http://localhost:8014/build/assets/app-0a7f7e13.css"/>
<link rel="modulepreload" href="http://localhost:8014/build/assets/app-498a8caa.js"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8014/build/assets/app-0a7f7e13.css"/>
<script type="module" src="http://localhost:8014/build/assets/app-498a8caa.js"></script>

As you can see, it seems that the links to the CSS and JS files have each been added back to the page.
A mistake that can be seen in the above outputs is that a js file with the link tag is attached to the page, which is not correct.
This is my vite.config.js file:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});


"...is that a js file with the link tag is attached to the page, which is not correct." It is correct when using rel="modulepreload"

Also notice that the first <link> has rel="preload", not rel="stylesheet"
